# Renaming an account in AD makes it working in a hidden way

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, windows-10

I'm using windows server 2016 with a single domain and a windows 10 client machine as a test lab.

I've started clean and fresh so I decided to renamed my AD administrator account from (administrator) to (admin) using active directory rename popup menu, everything went fine at this point.

However I found that the old administrator account name(administrator) is still working!
this means now I got 2 admins! while I can see only one admin which is (admin) the new renamed in AD.

When I tested I found that I can use both accounts name on the user machine (administrator) + (admin)!

I've tried to rename it again from (admin) to (adminx) the rename process went fine but again I got (administrator) + (admin) + (adminx) are working!! but hidden! and the only account name I can see is the new renamed (adminx)!!

I tried to change the password for (adminx), the change went successfully, however I still can use (administrator) + (admin) with their old passwords on the clients machine!!

I Shutdown, restart, update both, used ADSI, AD advanced view, net user command, PowerShell commands, regedit, user profiles they only point and show the existents of (adminx) but they don't show the old two (administrator) + (admin)!

I thought it might be saved credentials so I tried to work offline on the client machine and it turn out that it will not accept any of the two old names, but when I connect to the AD, It will accept them with their old passwords although they are not listed in the AD, I only have the (adminx) shown.

I don't know where are they hidden but they are still working somehow and hidden somewhere, I can use them to do any administrator work with full rights but I cannot login using them!, I can only use them when UAC asking for admin rights!

So anybody knows where can I find those hidden accounts? so I can delete them ?? or at least we know how many more are there in our systems ?

Comment: Did you also verify the UPN has changed?

Comment: The original account which is (administrator) doesn't have a UPN when I renamed it to (admin) a popup window asked for UPN names so I renamed and added one to be admin@labtest.lan but its not the case all the renames even without UPN suffix just create a hidden user !

Comment: I tired to use ldp to see that maybe a lost account is there, I found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Perform your various logon methods and then look for Security log [EventId 4624 "An account was successfully logged on"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4624). It will give you the account name to security ID mapping plus the logon type. A logon type 2 indicates interactive, but type 11 is a cached logon. The details of that eventid should help you determine what's going on.

Comment: I've used the GPO to set the cached logon to 0 then again to 10 it deleted those cached/hidden accounts perfectly.

Comment: Glad you found out what was going on. The Protected Users group should also prevent your highly privileged accounts from being allowed to logon using cached credentials.

Comment: U know what? It turns out that I did wipe some of the machines but the majority is still using the cached credentials without being deleted, although I have tried various ways of deleting the catched credentials on the clients PCs, however they still can use them by removing the network cable and using these catches credentials again!!

Comment: Cached logon exists for exactly that reason: When the Domain Controller cannot be reached, the user can still access their device using a domain credential. You can lower the default value of 10 cached logons to 1 and then the system will purge any other cached credentials except for the user logging in normally. I'd recommend implementing a local admin password management solution like LAPS to ensure you can always get into the system using local credentials in case of an emergency.

Comment: The idea is admin password got compromised and we cannot remove it due to its a catched creadantial now in every machine, renaming or deleting get things to worse which is another catched ones although I'm eliminating all catched credentials

Comment: Credential caching doesn't have to be the problem here. Users may depend on this when the domain is unavailable. Having a domain administrative account cached on every system is a problem. Break your access up into roles and never allow a Domain/Enterprise Admin to log into a workstation. Check out Microsoft's tiered administration model for a better way of controlling privileged access.